# Needs to understand Backbone main function

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm trying to learn advance JavaScript and some people suggested to learn from [Backbone.js source code](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js)

```
(function(factory) {

   //There are some lines of code here...

})(function(root, Backbone, _, $) {

   //Many lines of code here 

});
```

- Is the `factory` in `(function(factory)`, the root that is in `(function(root, Backbone, _, $)`?
- What is factory?
- What is Backbone?
- What is _?
- What is $?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking at the [AMD module pattern](http://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html#definition), which I wouldn't spend too much time focusing on. `factory` *is* the function with "Many lines of code". The first function you encounter calls `factory` after it loads Backbone's dependencies - underscore.js (`_`) and jquery.js (`$`). Think of it as a dependency-injection version of:

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="underscore.js"></script>
<script>
function Backbone() {
  // do stuff that depends on underscore and jquery
}
</script>
```

---

*Is the factory in (function(factory), the root that is in (function(root, Backbone, _, $)?*

No, answered above

*What is factory?*

The guts of the Backbone library which is initialized once its dependencies are loaded

*What is Backbone?*

An empty object to start out with `root.Backbone = factory(root, exports, _, $);` where exports is initialized to `{}` for a given module

*What is _?*

The [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) library

*What is $?*

The [jquery](https://jquery.com/) library

Comment: Thank you so much, then, this style of code is from AMD module pattern. What pattern do you suggest me to learn which is both useful and easy?

Comment: Glad to help, I would focus on [ES6 modules](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_modules.html), even though there isn't 100% support everywhere yet - it is a solid and simple pattern that has a lot of traction.

Answer (score 3):

Let’s make it a bit easier by naming the anonymous functions.

```
(function definingFn(factory) {

   //There are some lines of code here...

})(function factoryFn(root, Backbone, _, $) {

   //Many lines of code here 

});
```

It could also be written like this:

```
function definingFn(factory) {/* code here */}
function factoryFn(root, Backbone, _, $) {/* code here */}
definingFn(factoryFn);
```

So, `definingFn` receives `factoryFn` as named argument `factory`. So `factory` is `factoryFn`, the function you pass to the first function as argument.

Then inside of the `definingFn`, other variables you are asking about are being defined:

```
(function(factory) {

  // Establish the root object, `window` (`self`) in the browser, or `global` on the server.
  // We use `self` instead of `window` for `WebWorker` support.
  var root = (typeof self == 'object' && self.self === self && self) ||
            (typeof global == 'object' && global.global === global && global);

  // Set up Backbone appropriately for the environment. Start with AMD.
  if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
    define(['underscore', 'jquery', 'exports'], function(_, $, exports) {
      // Export global even in AMD case in case this script is loaded with
      // others that may still expect a global Backbone.
      root.Backbone = factory(root, exports, _, $);
    });

  // Next for Node.js or CommonJS. jQuery may not be needed as a module.
  } else if (typeof exports !== 'undefined') {
    var _ = require('underscore'), $;
    try { $ = require('jquery'); } catch (e) {}
    factory(root, exports, _, $);

  // Finally, as a browser global.
  } else {
    root.Backbone = factory(root, {}, root._, (root.jQuery || root.Zepto || root.ender || root.$));
  }

})(function(root, Backbone, _, $) {
  // more code here
})
```

There are several conditions that detect the environment of this script and each invoke the `factory` function with certain value.

Let’s review just the "browser" environment:

First line in `definingFn` defines the `root`, the global object. The library is using `self` global object ([read about it on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/self)) in case of browser environment.

Then empty object is supplied as in place of `Backbone` named argument, to use as a "namespace" to attach things defined in `factoryFn`.

Then global variable for `underscore` library, which uses `_` as its name is passed.

Then there’s `$` object, which can be jQuery, Zepto or Ender, one of these libs, which Backbone is using for event delegation and XHR.

Comment: A good answer, but ELI5.  I think one is just looking for definitions of the structure parts.

Comment: Thank you so much, very useful answer. I did not know much of it +1